# What are the rules of forming structures with 'no'?

Tags: negation

> I cannot find information on the rules of forming structures with 'no' as in There is *no* milk ('no' + an uncountable noun). Thare are *no* bananas in the fridge ('no" + a plural countable noun).

I have been told that sentences where there is a singular countable noun after 'no' should be avoided as they aren't grammatical as in 'There's *no banana* in the fridge'.

I have checked 'Practical English Usage' by Michael Swan (3rd edition) and 'The Teacher's Grammar of English' by Ron Cowan (Cambridge) but failed to find anything on the matter.

A reference to a reliable source is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/followed-singular-plural-noun/ This may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no banana in the fridge

is not ungrammatical but it is idiomatic only if the speaker is asserting that fact *emphatically*, perhaps when telling another person that they are incorrect for insisting that there is indeed a banana in the fridge.

> Do we have any bananas?
>   -- Check the fridge. I'm sure I saw some yesterday.
>   No, there are no bananas in the fridge.
>   -- Are you sure? You're not giving a lazy-ass little peek like you usually do? Did you check the drawers too?
>   As I said, there is no banana in the fridge.